# Disable scrolling for mouse-over in ComboBox (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to disable the autoscrolling effect in a `ComboBox` Dropdown? The Problem is when the mouse is hovered over the last element of the open `ComboBox` it automatically scrolls to the next element.

And in my case the `ComboBox` is at the bottom of the screen and the list is displayed upwards and when i open the `ComboBox` and move the mouse, it scrolls down immediately.. My XAML looks like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="serverSelection" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Width="268" Height="54" FontSize="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="xenappts01" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="280" Height="54" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="xenappts02" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="280" Height="54" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="xenappts03" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="280" Height="54" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="xenappts04" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="280" Height="54" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="xenappts05" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="280" Height="54" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="xenappts05c" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="280" Height="54" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
</ComboBox>
```

I tried to set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` but that didnt work.

This is what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcwJX.gif

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add an example to your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could handle the `RequestBringIntoView` event for the `ComboBoxItem` containers:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="ComboBox_RequestBringIntoView"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

---

```
private void ComboBox_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I just recently ran into this issue as well and while there is a lot of help out there on the subject none of them work as gracefully as this solution. Very simple and doesn't require a crazy work around that introduces new and exciting problems.

Comment: This resolves the problem, but it's not great for a long list where you actually want to bring the selected item into view when the list first opens.

Comment: @Edgar in `ComboBox_RequestBringIntoView` add the following: `if (((UIElement)e.Source).IsKeyboardFocusWithin) e.Handled = true;`